# To capitalize "department" or not

Tags: capitalization

When using the word "department" after the name of a department, does one capitalize it?  For example, "Advertising Department?"

Answer (score 15):

When using the word 'department' (or 'group', 'committee', and the like) as part of a recognized name it would be capitalized:

> Bill recently joined the Advertising Department.

If using 'department' not as part of a specific name it would be lower case:

> We had a party to welcome Bill to the
>   department.

As a further note, you could also drop the 'Department' and re-write the first sentence as:

> Bill recently moved to Advertising.

But if using 'advertising' not as the name of a specific department, but rather as a field of expertise, you would write:

> Bill works in advertising.

Comment: Should department be capitalised if it is used in the following context; "The department agreed ..."?

Comment: In looking at it I can't see why it would be capitalised, unless you put something specific in front of it as in "The Accounts Department agreed ..."

Comment: @Snubian: Capitalization would also be used in situations where e.g. a contract leads of with "The Department shall refer to the Widget Maintenance Department of Acme Corporation"; in such a case, when Department is capitalized it would always refer to that particular department, even in contexts that were talking about other departments.

Comment: @supercat Yes; even second-hand specification, where the complete first-hand term needs a capital, requires one.