# Should I capitalize "corporate communications" if it refers to a business department?

Tags: capitalization

If I say "In November, corporate communications rejected the proposal," should I capitalize "corporate communications" if it refers to a team or department? Does this vary by style guide?

I've tried searching specifically for the rule for this according to the AP style guide (I looked for online commentary on this as I don't have the actual guide yet) and haven't had any luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Question is a duplicate of this one, which (spoiler warning) recommends capitalisation: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18236/to-capitalize-department-or-not

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should capitalise “Corporate Communications” as it is a proper noun - the name of a distinct part of the company.

Without capitalisation there is also potential ambiguity. Your sentence could mean something like, “In November communications from the company rejected the proposal.” Whereas the meaning you want to convey can be rephrased, “In November the Corporate Communications Department (Section, Area, etc) rejected the proposal.”

This reference is relevant: [Business Writing](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2007/09/sales-departmen.html)